# Path to Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, advice

What do I need to learn to start on the rigorous study of differential geometry?  I'm about to start my 3rd undergrad year at school, and have taken Cal 1-3, Linear Algebra, Elementary Number Theory, and ODEs.

If I want to take the most direct path to studying differential geometry, what should I start learning now?  Should I start on Real Analysis or Topology?  Should I just pick up Spivak's *Intro to Differential Geometry*?  My multivariable calculus class did not cover differential forms, so should I read his *Calculus on Manifolds* or Munkres' *Analysis on Manifolds* first?

I'm pretty sure that I want to study differential geometry in grad school and I'd like to start on it before then (ideally, I'd like to be able to publish something -- not necessarily extremely deep -- in diff geo before applying to grad schools).

So what path should I take to self-study it?

NOTE: My school has 1 undergrad course in Differential Geometry available in the Spring, so I'll probably do that next year, but I'd rather start now and go well beyond whatever I'm going to learn in that class.

Comment: I remember using a D.G. text by Boothby, thought it was very readable.

Comment: Ted recommended that, too (below).  So I'll definitely be checking that out.

Answer (score 6):

To do a standard *undergraduate* diff geo course, you don't need much beyond multivariable calculus and linear algebra. But if you want to pursue it at the graduate level, first and foremost, you need a solid foundation in multivariable analysis (with emphasis on the Inverse and Implicit Function Theorems and differential forms).

Comment: So would that be Spivak's or Munkres' books?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes, those books will do fine. Munkres is a bit more readable — basically a rewrite of Spivak.

Comment: And then is Spivak's Intro to Diff Geo a good follow-up?  What exactly is the level of that series (undergrad or grad)?  Will I need something else after that?

Comment: Spivak's 5 volume book is way too wordy, but volume 1 is a good start. This is all graduate level. This is not easy stuff to "self-study." Boothby's introductory book covers things in a lot fewer pages and is a good starting point. But there's still plenty of time to learn this in graduate school.

Comment: When I say "self-study", I don't mean to imply that I'll be learning it in a vacuum.  There are several professors at my school that I have a rapport with that I'm sure will be willing to help when I have a question.  But I'm on summer break right now -- so I don't see them everyday-- and trying to plan out my next couple of years.

Comment: So your recommendation is to read Munkres' *Analysis on Manifolds* and then try Boothby's *An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry*?  Am I going to need any topology or real analysis for those?  Is there anything else that I'll need to study grad-level differential geometry, when I'm ready?

Comment: Oh, you definitely need basics of real analysis before you do Munkres, and some point set topology to do graduate differential geometry. How have you decided on this without even an undergraduate course? For that, you might start with my text, available in pdf on my webpage (see the profile).

Comment: I'm not for sure -- I could change my mind at any time.  But it seems interesting, and I've decided to try to shoot for something as a means to get motivated to work on math this summer.

Comment: So I guess the sequence should be something like: your notes in parallel with baby Rudin -> Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds -> Munkres' Topology (or maybe Janich's book?) -> Boothby's book on DG.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Very ambitious. But get started! :)